# how to combine the same 2 records into 1 same record in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I have been looking for various ways but still not found it?

this is more like merge and center in Excel, but what if we implement it in MS Access?

[image]

Comment: Eh... Access is a relational database, not a spreadsheet program. This is fundamentally not possible.

Comment: What databases should I use to be as image i share?

Comment: None, databases aren't spreadsheet programs. If you want a spreadsheet, use a spreadsheet program.

Comment: if we make a report from the database results? is it possible ?

Comment: No, not unless you use a spreadsheet program to make that report.

Comment: ohh okay , thanks Erik

Comment: Best way would be, as @ErikvonAsmuth, suggested, using a spreadsheet program to make the report. If your data is already in Access, just design something to export the data to Excel, and then design a macro in Excel to combine Cells, (or use Pivot Tables).

Comment: okay , ill try it

Comment: In an Access report, you can for a textbox set the property HideDuplicates to True. That's the closest you can get.

Comment: how to HideDuplicate in access report ?

Comment: HideDuplicates is property of textbox. It is on the Format tab of Property Sheet, almost at end of list.

Comment: okay thanks , it works